# Asynchronous viewer update

Tags: actionscript-3, exception, actionscript, flash-builder, indexoutofboundsexception

While debugging in **Flash Builder 4.6** I get the following popup:

[image]

`Try catch` blocks do not catch this exception and the application doesn't throw any exceptions when running in release.

I have never seen this before.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is not thrown by your application. This is an `Eclipse` (Flash Builder) exception. It's written by programmers like us too, so there are some bugs :)

If it's frequent and you want to get rid of it, I suggest going to your workspace and deleting the `.metadata` folder, but be aware that it **will delete all your configuration** of the `Flash Builder` IDE.

Only try the above method if restarting `Flash Builder` doesn't help.

More on the exception thrown:

First of all, exceptions (Errors in case of Actionscript) which are thrown by your code do not show up in a separate `Flash Builder` window, that's how you can tell wether it is yours or IDEs.

Other than that if you look closely at the exception it says `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, that's a `Java` exception, not an `Actionscript` one.